# sendmail sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, sendmail

I cannt send mail from php script although I can send it from command line with sendmail and

php sendMyMail.php

I have already tried these

1. httpd is running as apache user and I added apache user to smmsp group
2. httpd_can_sendmail --> on
3. ```
   SELinux status:                 enabled
   SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
   Current mode:                   permissive
   Mode from config file:          enforcing
   Policy version:                 24
   Policy from config file:        targeted
   ```

But in httpd error_log still showing this error

> sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Can anyone have any idea?  I do really appreciate all your suggestions and really exhausted with this one.

Comment: Have you check permission try giving by # chmod -v 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: yes I did but no luck . thanks

Comment: What are the permissions for /usr/sbin/sendmail?
Are you running on a server where you have access to the sendmail binary?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     21 Jan 16 17:35 sendmail ->/etc/alternatives/mta
Here is another problem so strange I changed to 744 last time , it was reset

Answer (score 0):

That you can send emails from the command line does not mean that any user can (apache for instance).

Check that apache can actually send emails:

```
sudo -u apache sendmail root@localhost
```

Read the mail logfile (usually /var/log/mail.log) to see what happened. Inbox of root is usually in /var/spool/mail/root ). Tipp: Use other user different from root if you don't want to use root as a guinea pig.

Comment: hi thanks , I've run that command there is no log in maillog,  however it doest show any error as well and sendmail command doest work with apache user . and I run sudo -u php sendMyMail.php and still got this error sh: /usr/sbin/sendmail: Permission denied

Comment: Are you sure you have a user called 'php'? When you run php from the command line, the user executing the command is the user you are logged in (type whoami to see who you are). Running php through web server, apache is the user that runs php. What *nix system are you using?

Comment: Thank you very much for all of your help.

I changed send_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail -t -i and I changed permission chmod -v 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail.sendmail

It is working now. It is definitely permission problem. I havent sorted it out with /usr/sbin/sendmail. Thanks a lot anyway .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1` you need to allow apache connect outside: `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`